# Highcharts multiple data on single point in series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to provide multiple data points on a single point inside a series. In easy way, on single x axis point, i need to show two y axis points. But when i provide multiple data points, in a series, it show the last on in the graph.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nazarhussain/a9dB6/7/) has the basic implementation of the scenario. Notice that first series has 4 points and second does have 3. But in graph only 3 are shown.

Comment: I think highcharts expects that all series be the same length. Is there a reason that you need to show series of different lengths?

Comment: Highcharts allow different series length. That is not a problem. I want to show two different points in Y-Axis for a single X-Axis. e.g. Today i got total of 15 orders but 3 were dropped. So i want to show first point on 15 and then it would drop to 12 for the same date. That is possible in scatter graph, but i want to show this in line graph.

Comment: Check this example I made, it has two series that both have an x value with multiple points. http://jsfiddle.net/RKVgx/

Comment: Yes that is what i required. Please add an answer for it so that i can mark it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this example I made, it has two series that both have an x value with multiple points.
[Example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RKVgx/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [[6, 540], [7, 540], [7, 1620], [8, 1620]]
    },{
        data: [[6, 340], [7, 340], [7, 620], [8, 620]]
    }]
});
```

Highcharts will render both values for x=7, connecting them with a line.